# 漢直winでtt-codeの使い方が分からない

Tags: windows

windows7で漢直winを使っています。
その中にtt.tblがあり、tt-codeも使える様になっています。

この中で例えばａのキーストロークはどうなるんだろうか。
右表プリフィックスとか左表プリフィックスとかでは
出て来ないんだが。

fjを先頭にしての打鍵と、jfを先頭にしての打鍵
以外にもプリフィックスの指定が有ると思うが
そこらへんのキーストロークの指定の仕方が分からない。

ａに関しては、漢索窓では▽が出て3の後にQを
打鍵しなさいとなっている。

然し、最初のプリフィックスの▽にする方法が
分からない。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: プログラミングに関する質問というより、アプリケーションの使い方の質問だと思いますので、こちらで聞くより該当アプリケーションのユーザが多いであろうサイト(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tcode)などで質問された方が良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Windows7で漢直Win(1.28)を使っている者です。普段は別の漢直を使っているので`TT-code`のことはよく分かりませんが、私に分かる範囲でお答えします。

結論を先に言うと、右表プレフィックスの`fj`や左表プレフィックスの`jf`を打ったときに`▽`や`▲`マークが表示されるようにはなっていないようです。

`tt.tbl`の中のこの行

> ＃define prefix /▲/26,23/▲○/▲/:/▽/23,26/▽○/▽/

と同じものが漢直Win添付のドキュメントにも引用されていて、「プレフィックス拡張型の入力方式における、文字ヘルプの表示指定です」という説明があるので、漢索窓の表示や`44`や`45`で表示されるヘルプ用の設定なのです。

`fj`や`jf`と同じように、2ストロークをプレフィックスにして入力できる文字を拡張するには、`tt.tbl`の`{`と`}`で囲まれた2階層の親ブロックの中に2階層の子ブロックを作る必要があります。（1打鍵ごとに階層が深くなっていきます）

子ブロックの作り方は、`tt.tbl`をエディタで開いて、`fj`の両隣の`fh`と`fk`で入力される`愛`と`宝`を検索してみれば分かります。`愛`と`宝`の間には文字の代りに`{`と`}`で囲まれた2階層のブロックが入っているはずです。

これと同じ要領で、親ブロックのどこかに文字が割り当てられていない空き地を見つけて、同じ構造の子ブロックを作ってやればいいのです。（このとき、子ブロックの中の`{`と`}`で囲まれた孫ブロックを`"`と`"`で囲んだ文字に置き換えれば、プレフィックス＋1打鍵で文字が入力できることになります）

ご質問の主旨と少しずれてしまったかもしれませんが、今のところ私に分かることはこれくらいです。

(プログラミングに関する質問ではないという御意見についての付記)

簡単に回答が得られそうもない質問があることを知り、その質問に回答するためにこのサイトに参加しました。たしかにこれは「漢直Win」というソフトの使い方に関する質問なので、この場にはふさわしい内容ではなさそうです。他のサイトに同じ質問があれば、そちらの方に回答することにします。